# time(NULL) returning different time

Tags: c, time

I am trying to get current time in C using `time_t current_time = time(NULL)`.
As I understand, it would return me the current time of system.
I am later trying to convert it into GMT time using struct `tm* gmt = gmtime(&current_time)`.

I print both times using `ctime()` and `asctime()` functions.

The current time on my system is GMT + 1. But `gmtime()` returns me the same time as `current_time` is. I could not understand why `gmtime()` is returning me same time. Any help will be appreciated.

Ok here is the code and the output: Current time that windows is showing is 17:54 (Stockholm zone; GMT+1). I want something to return me 15:54. Or perhaps my understanding is wrong ...

```
time_t current_time = time(NULL);

struct tm* gmt = gmtime(&current_time);
struct tm* loc = localtime(&current_time);

printf("current time: %s\n", ctime(&current_time));
printf("gmt time %s\n", asctime(gmt));
printf("local time %s\n", asctime(loc));
```

Output:

```
current time: Mon Oct  8 17:54:06 2012

gmt time Mon Oct  8 17:54:06 2012

local time Mon Oct  8 17:54:06 2012
```

**Accepted Solution:** **From Simes**

That's probably your problem. Check the value of your TZ environment variable; if not present, it will default to GMT. Cygwin doesn't automatically pick up the time zone setting from Windows. See also [localtime returns GMT for windows programs running on cygwin shells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655003/localtime-returns-gmt-for-windows-programs-running-on-cygwin-shells)

Comment: Perhaps the time zone is not configured correctly on your system?

Comment: I have checked the timezone on my system and its GMT + 1 (thats what windows is saying).

Comment: Also, localtime return the same value as gmtime and current_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time_t type holds a value representing the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch.
A tm type holds a calendar value.

gmtime() just converts system time (which is always UTC) from time_t to tm. That's why the values are the same. If you want a representation of your local time (GMT+1), that's what localtime() is for.

Comment: I am stumped. The only thing I can think of is some weirdness with the compiler or similar that you're using, but the code you describe, as far as I can see, ought to do what you're expecting of it. Unless it's running in a virtual machine, in which case it's the system and local time settings of the VM which are relevant here.

Comment: I am compiling the program using cygwin (gcc).

Comment: That's probably your problem. Check the value of your TZ environment variable; if not present, it will default to GMT. Cygwin doesn't automatically pick up the time zone setting from Windows. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655003/localtime-returns-gmt-for-windows-programs-running-on-cygwin-shells

Answer (score 1):

`time()` returns the number of seconds since epoch. <strike>Which is equal to UTC (aka GMT)</strike>

Epoch was 1.1.1970, 00:00:00 in Greenwich, UK.

So in fact `time()` does not return a time, but a time **difference**.

Comment: UTC is not aka GMT, they are 2 different things ,even they are almost same value, but not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Run the debugger over these two lines:

```
struct tm* gmt = gmtime(&current_time);

struct tm* loc = localtime(&current_time);
```

Break on the second line, watch members of gmt and when you execute the second line - you will see that some gmt members change value. Apparently some static memory is used by the library. So save the results of the first statement before running the second