# PhantomJS: cygwin returns different JS date than windows cmd

Tags: javascript, windows, cmd, cygwin, phantomjs

I'm seeing something strange when running PhantomJS through Cygwin versus a windows command prompt.  Specifically, the value of a JavaScript Date object returned is different depending on the terminal you running out of.

I'm using a Win7 64bit machine, with PhantomJS 1.9.7 and Cygwin 1.7.28(0.271/5/3).

Results from CYGWIN:

```
/cygdrive/c
$ phantomjs
phantomjs> var d = new Date("2013/10/01")
undefined
phantomjs> d
"2013-09-30T23:00:00.000Z"
```

Results from Win CMD:

```
C:\> phantomjs
phantomjs> var d = new Date("2013/10/01")
undefined
phantomjs> d
"2013-10-01T07:00:00.000Z"
```

Any idea why CYGWIN would return `"2013-09-30T23:00:00.000Z"` and CMD returns `"2013-10-01T07:00:00.000Z"`?

Comment: I have the same "problem". On Win7 32bit there is a different timezone (by 1 hour) selected inside phantomjs. I tried setting it with `export TZ=$(tzset)` in the cygwin environment, but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with running phantomjs / poltergeist automated tests under cygwin / babun.

```
unset TZ
```

solved the problem, put it in your .zshrc or .bashrc or similar for a permanent fix.

Credit to: [localtime returns GMT for windows programs running on cygwin shells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11655003/localtime-returns-gmt-for-windows-programs-running-on-cygwin-shells)